# infinite loop unable to close loop in Switch Statements

Tags: java, loops, do-while

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MenuFastFood {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s;
        char order;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        s = keyboard.next();
        s = s.toUpperCase();
        order = s.charAt(0);

        do {
        switch(order) { 
            case 'A': 
                System.out.println("CheeseBurger");
                System.out.println("Onion Rings");
                System.out.println("Soda");
                break;

            case 'B':
                System.out.println("Hot dog");
                System.out.println("Fries");
                System.out.println("Milk Shake");
                break;

            default: 
                System.out.println("error");
                return;     

            case 'X':
                System.out.println("EXIT"); 
                break;          
            }
        }while(order != 'X');
    }
```

my program is suppose to pick an item based on the character enter in to keybaord and then loops back if another item is selected. when i run this and pick an item. it loops that item for ever. How do i get that to stop and makes it able for me to select another item?

Comment: You would need to read some input *inside* the loop.

Comment: Move the 3 statements before the `do` to inside the loop before the `switch`.

Comment: and it works. thanks. im new to code and i still get a little lost on some of details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your code for reading input to inside do..while

```
        s = keyboard.next();
        s = s.toUpperCase();
        order = s.charAt(0);
```